# How can I call a constructor with two parameters from thymeleaf textbox?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have a textfield

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" th:value="*{name}" th:field="*{name}"/>
```

and an entity Costumer which has two constructor

```
Costumer(String name)
Costumer(Locale locale, String name)
```

With the textbox above, only the first constructor gets called! How can I call my constructor which has two parameters, and how can I pass the locale to it?

Answer (score 0):

In your place I would use form.

TestForm:

```
public class TestForm {

    private String name;
    private String locale;

    public TestForm() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }

    public void setLocale(String locale) {
        this.locale = locale;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TestForm [name=" + name + ", locale=" + locale + "]";
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = GET)
public String test(final ModelMap modelMap) {
    modelMap.put("testForm", new TestForm());
return "/test";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = POST)
public String posttest(@ModelAttribute("testForm") final TestForm testForm) {
    System.out.println(testForm);
return "redirect:/somewhere/else";
}
```

test.html:

```
    <form th:object="${testForm}" method="post">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" th:value="*{name}" th:field="*{name}"/>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="locale" th:value="*{locale}" th:field="*{locale}"/>

        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
```